# check And Count Value over php array

Tags: php

i am trying to count the number of times value is between 2 elements of array
first array is the company grade

Comps Esg Grades

```
$arr1 = [1,2,3,9,5,6,20,35,9,10];
```

the second array is the compere  array

Final Compare

```
$arr2 = [0,2.2,10.4,20,30,44,60];
```

what i would like to achieve is
the number of times company is between to elements of array

first company grade is 1. so i am iterating over the arr2
like so to check if the value of 1 is between the elements
`[0] and [1] [1] and [2] [2] and [3]`
and so on

if the value is true so i add 1
when i am checking the next company value in this case its 2
so i need to add 1 to the previews check so the result should be 2
because i have 2 grade that in between 0 and 2.2

this is my code:

```
//Comps Esg Grades
$arr1 = [1,2,3,9,5,6,20,35,9,10];
//Final Compare
$arr2 = [0,1.7,10.4,20,30,44,60];
$countArray = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $r){
   
    foreach ($arr2 as $keyMain =>  $r2){
        $countArray[$keyMain] = 0;
       
    }
}

foreach ($arr1 as $r){
  
    foreach ($arr2 as $key =>  $r2){
        if($r2 > $r && $r2 < $arr2[$key + 1]){
            $currentVal = $countArray[$key];
            $countArray[$key] = $currentVal + 1;
         }
        
    }
}
```

and this is the result

```
   Array
   (
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 0
   )
```

Comment: Ok, but do you have a question or some problem to report?

Comment: I definitely don't understand the task.  Why in the world is `$countArray[$keyMain] = 0;` inside of a nested loop??? Do you want to map all values to zero?  ...it just keeps overwriting itself on each run.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: yes. my problem is that i don't get the current answer as you can see in the result, so my question is what am i doing wrong and how can i get the correct answer.
thank you

Comment: You had better show us what the correct answer is

Comment: What is `$run` doing in the first foreach loop. It does nothing and is not used

Comment: in the first loop i create an array that i can update the count by the key.

Comment: _"and how can i get the correct answer"_ - what _is_ the correct answer, based on the shown input data? Your explanation sounds overly convoluted - can the whole thing be summed up as, you want to count how many of the values fall into each of those intervals?

Comment: I get the feeling I have seen this or a very similiar question yesterday. Again you dont need `$run` all you need is `$arr2[$key+1]` but with a array bounds check to make sure you dont run off the end of the array

Comment: yes. this is what i am trying to do. i am sorry if i am not clear enough

Comment: So what is the exact result you want with the given input data then - `[2,6,1,1,1,0]`? )For the first set of example data, you cleverly managed to use a different set in the code you have shown ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run first on the ranges array ($arr2) and for each of those find how many items from the first array fit. The exact details though really depends on the expected result.

```php
//Comps Esg Grades
$arr1 = [1,2,3,9,5,6,20,35,9,10];
//Final Compare
$arr2 = [0,1.7,10.4,20,30,44,60];
$countArray = [];


for ($i=0; $i<count($arr2)-1; $i++) {
    $min = $arr2[$i];
    $max = $arr2[$i+1];
    $countArray[$i] = 0;

    for ($j=0; $j<count($arr1); $j++) {
        
        if ($arr1[$j] >= $min && $arr1[$j] <= $max) {
            $countArray[$i]++;
        }
    }
}

print_r($countArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 0
)
```